# ammending a string inside a function

Tags: function, nsstring

I need to create a string in `Xcode` that I can keep adding to every time a calculation is performed within a function.

```
if(answer != 0) answer1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d / %d = %d \n", answer, number[i], myans];

return 1;
```

I need the 'answer1' value to ammend itself after each true if statement. for example :-

first correct statement :-

```
answer1 now equals "10 / 5 = 2 \n"
```

second correct answer :-

```
answer1 now needs to equal "10 / 5 = 2 \n 200 / 10 = 20 \n"
```

and so on until the loop finishes.

The value of the string has to be available outside of the function.

Answer (score 1):

You can try somthing like this

```
answer1 = [answer1 stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d / %d = %d \n", answer, number[i], myans];
```

Hope it will work...

Comment: Great that seems to work with the calculation thanks.

Comment: The problem I have now is that I need to write the text to a UITextWindow from within the function.

Comment: So :- answer1 = [answer1 stringByAppendingFormat:@"A1 %d / %d = %d \n", answer, number[i], myans];
[self.TextWin setText:answer1];

Comment: @ user2862680: you can try to make a UILabel and set the answer1 to UILabel's text and add that UILabel to your view